# Rails countdown gem or javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Within my rails 4 app, i'm trying to set a countdown in one of my views.

I've tried using this gem: https://github.com/jnbt/countdown

In my gem file I added:

```
gem 'countdown'
```

I then ran bundle install which ran smoothly.

Then I added this in my application.js file:

```
//= require countdown
```

And then I tried running this from the terminal as instructed:

```
rails generate countdown:install
```

Which resulted in this error:

```
Could not find generator countdown:install
```

I then added this tag in my application.html.erb file:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'countdown' %>
```

And finally in my view, I added:

```
 <%= countdown Time.now + 28.hours %>
```

Which is giving me this error:

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound in Posts#index

couldn't find file 'countdown'
```

What is causing this? Is there any alternative to this gem? I would just like as simple countdown in my view. Can I just use some other javascript countdown? (I'm just worried about the countdown starting from when the user refreshes the browser, I need it to start from a permanent point, a particular date and time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs say the generator file simply copies countdown.js to the public/javascripts directory.  You should be able to do that yourself.  Just copy the code at:

https://bitbucket.org/mckamey/countdown.js/raw/tip/countdown.js

Create a file `public/javascripts/countdown.js` and paste in the code.

Comment: my javascript folder is in my app/assets folder, should I create a javascript folder within my public directory as well to put this file in it?

Comment: I added the file and now i'm getting this error: undefined method `countdown'

Comment: Honestly the gem doesn't look very well made. The readme says `Running the generator will copy 'countdown.js' over to the public\javascripts directory`, so that's why I suggested it as a solution. It's not how I would have done it though...

Comment: Here is the current script I am using   <script>  
  var clock = document.getElementById("countdown-holder")  
    , targetDate = new Date(2050, 00, 01); // Jan 1, 2050; 
  clock.innerHTML = countdown(targetDate).toString();  
  setInterval(function(){  
    clock.innerHTML = countdown(targetDate).toString();  
  }, 1000);  
</script>     How do I set it give me a countdown of exactly one week from now?